# How python regex to find or search only the exact world/text

Tags: python

I have process "httpd" in the below example which is running as full path as "`/usr/sbin/httpd`" , I'm using a python  script to catch these process but the reason when i search for "`httpd`" it takes "`httpd`" even if it has anything attached pre or suffixed example: "`KKhttpdS_PS`" or "`which_httpd_running`" which i don't want.

Saying that, i would like to search unique string "`httpd`" or if it has  "`/` or `/usr/bin/`  or `/usr/sbin/` or `/usr/local/bin/`" like in below that's okay, but it shouldn't have anything after "`httpd`" ... that's the requirement...

```
10971 apache   /usr/sbin/httpd              1-06:16:59
10972 apache   /usr/sbin/httpd              1-06:16:59
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example of an input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you need.

`r'httpd\s+'`

And `\s+` means one or more spaces.

Comment: `\s` matches a space character. to match one or more spaces, it should be `\s+`

Comment: @Sraw, thx .. i'll check it , though i need to ensure it should not have anything before apart  from "`/`".

Comment: @rockypy17 That's easy, `r'/httpd\s+'`, thx for @falsetru 's advice.